# Anti-debug in android

Tags: android

Anyone did the actual android anti-debug check. I know there are things like

```
IsDebuggerConnected()

boolean isDebuggable = (0 != (getApplicationInfo().flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_DEBUGGABLE));
```

I'm looking for something which is like ptrace using NDK or any other mechanism where the handle of the process cannot be debugged by others. Like, a self-debug in diff thread when the application starts which doesnot allow other debugger to get hold of the process.

Any insight on this will be very useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to reliably prevent debugging and reverse engineering your application.  You can make it more difficult by obfiscation,  but  if it is worth to reverse engineer , it will be done ( Sovjet IT specialists did managed to reverse engineer System 360 and even patched it in machine code )  - so it is just not worth the effort.

Comment: I'm just wondering if there is a way to make reverse engineering a lil complex. I know obfuscation is a method. Any others that u could think of? (like self-debug the app by itself etc.,)

Comment: reverse engineering is not easy task in general ( even if you have sources writen by someone else ;) ) , and protecting against it is usually not worth the effort